# Magento2.2 How to get userContext into ScopeConfig

Tags: magento2, api, magento2.2.6, system-config

It's more a core logic issue than a technical issue!

I created one new table for admin_user: **admin_user_config_data**

```
|config_id|user_id|path|value
```

And, like in core_config_data, in this new table will be stored the data from the specific admin_user.

I tried to create a new scope, but It's very complicated, and looking the code I realized that magento create a new cache from every scope and every time that I need to change the config.

Aways that I need to run this line:

```
$this->_reinitableConfig->reinit()
```

Well. Than I created the plugin below that search for the config path in my new table:

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface">
    <plugin name="Mine_User_ScopeConfigInterface" type="Mine\User\Plugin\ScopeConfig" />
</type>
```

**Mine\User\Plugin\ScopeConfig**

```
class ScopeConfig
{
    public function __construct(
        \Mine\User\Model\ResourceModel\UserConfigData\CollectionFactory $userConfigDataCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface $userContext
    )
    {
        $this->_userConfigDataCollectionFactory = $userConfigDataCollectionFactory;
        $this->_userContext = $userContext;
    }

    public function afterGetValue(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $subject,
        $result,
        $path,
        $scopeType = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        $scopeCode = null
    )
    {
        if ($this->_userContext && $this->_userContext->getUserId()) {
            $userConfigData = $this->_userConfigDataCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addFieldToFilter('path', $path)
                ->addFieldToFilter('user_id', $this->_userContext->getUserId())
                ->getFirstItem();

            if ($userConfigData->getId()) {
                return $userConfigData->getValue();
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

But if I do this, my API returns the message:

```
Consumer is not authorized to access %resources
```

Without the UserContextInterface in the constructor the API works normally.

**Anyone have any idea of how I can get the config stored in the admin_user_config_data after the value provided by the scopeConfig and with current logged in user? (The login is by api token provided by *V1/integration/admin/token*)**